# how to change joomla article link

Tags: joomla

in default joomla showing the linked articles in contents at the main page , how we can change it some where else ?

Example :

OLD : `http://localhost/newjoomla/index.php/2-uncategorised`

NEW : `http://localhost/newjoomla/index.php/menu-2/2-uncategorised`

Comment: This question is better for http://joomla.stackexchange.com

Comment: in there joomla tagg have 200 followers only .

Comment: But very active and focused.

Answer (score 1):

Altough your question isn't that clear ill try to answer.

1 - Go to: System > Global Configuration > **"SEO Settings" Tab**

2 - Then activate both **Search Engine Friendly URLs** and **Use URL Rewriting**

3 - Rename your `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess` in order for SEF urls to work

By then your url's will probably be much nicer, without the "index.php" thing in the middle.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: i know this but i want to change link , not friendly and remove index.php,but thanks for tour answer.

Comment: Are you using any components like "sh404sef"?

Your problem is that you want the OLD instead of the NEW?

Or the "NEW" is what you are looking for?

Try to be more expressive :)

Comment: Im looking for the new one